# Problem detecting the anlge of the phone - Mango API

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I've started recently to study the windows phone 7.1 (Mango) SDK. Is there a simple way to get the angle of the phone relative to the ground (a close prediction is also good)?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You use the [Accelerometer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.sensors.accelerometer%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431810(v=vs.92).aspx and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202984(v=vs.92).aspx